# Android: CountDownTimer in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, countdowntimer

I have an app that uses a `CountDownTimer` inside a `BraodcastReceiver`. The `CountDownTimer` can be for upwards of 1 hour. The timer shows the countdown in the Notifications area (second intervals).

Some users have reported that the app seems to hang on long count downs. The CountDownTimer is triggered by a widget.

Does anyone know if a `CountDownTimer` can be stopped and reclaimed by the OS?

The alternative would be to set a recurring alarm at 1 second intervals which runs a service. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if a CountDownTimer can be stopped and reclaimed by the OS?

Your process will be.

> The alternative would be to set a recurring alarm at 1 second intervals which runs a service.

That's not an option in any practical sense, if by "recurring alarm" you mean `AlarmManager`. `AlarmManager` is not designed for every-second events.

> Is there a better option?

This is one of the few cases that justifies a foreground service. Since you have a `Notification` anyway, and since your `AlarmManager` approach would keep the service around constantly anyway, you may as well dispense with the `AlarmManager` and use `startForeground()` to keep the service around. Update the `Notification` that you are using with `startForeground()`, and use `ScheduledExecutorService` to get control every second on a background thread.

When the countdown is done, call `stopForeground()` and `stopSelf()` to get rid of it all.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying I need to use code similar to the one on [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and that I should execute this code from a foreground service?